# Convert Subquery with ORDER BY in 'ON' clause to Join for optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT prod.ProductID, prod.Name, prod.ProdExtID, ls.ProdServiceID
FROM Products prod 
LEFT JOIN ProductServices ls ON ls.ProdServiceID=(SELECT ProdServiceID FROM 
ProductServices WHERE ProductID=prod.ProductID ORDER BY Modified DESC LIMIT 
1) ;
```

This query returns `175` rows

I want to convert this to JOIN.

I used below query:

```
SELECT prod.ProductID, prod.Name, prod.ProdExtID, ls1.ProductServicesID
FROM Products prod 
inner join ProductServices ls on ls.ProductID=prod.ProductID
inner JOIN (SELECT ProductServicesID, ProductID, max(Modified) as Modified
       FROM
      ProductServices group by Modified) as ls1 ON ls.ProductServicesID = 
  ls1.ProductServicesID and ls.Modified = ls1.Modified and ls.ProductID = 
  ls1.ProductID;
```

which doesn't return correct result. Can I get some direction on this.
The purpose is to optimize the query. Would it be good idea to use join in place of original query.

Thanks!

Comment: You should updated  your question and add  a proper data sample .. your actual result and the expected  result

Comment: *"which doesn't return correct result. Can I get some direction on this."* Common sense the first query used a `LEFT JOIN` , the second query never used a `LEFT JOIN` that alone is suspiciously odd...  Besides that i agree here with @scaisEdge suggestion see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938724/convert-subquery-with-order-by-in-on-clause-to-join-for-optimization)

Comment: ..also questions about performance should include `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` foreach table involved in the query/question including tables which are parent with foreign keys.. And the `EXPLAIN` output for the first query, optimisation might be just as simple as adding the correct indexe(s) for your query..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProductID
, Name
, ProdExtID
, ProdServiceID
FROM
(
SELECT prod.ProductID
, prod.Name
, prod.ProdExtID
, ls.ProdServiceID
, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ls.ProdServiceID ORDER BY ls.Modified DESC) AS rnk
FROM Products prod 
LEFT JOIN ProductServices ls ON ls.ProductID=prod.ProductID
) x
WHERE rnk = 1
```

So basically: your join needs to be on ProductID but you only want the most recent ProdServiceID, right?

Comment: That would most likely need to read the complete Products  and ProductServices tables ...

Comment: Potentially. The question is fairly unclear. I'm trying to provide an option to the OP.

Comment: Well, it's unclear if "optimize the query" means "make the query faster" or "re-factor the code to make it more readable"

Comment: *"Potentially"*, i am pretty sure of it, the MySQl optimizer handles this query like i said... Fair enough it is not that clear if the topicstarter is looking for performance or a code refactor..  Also this assume this topicstarter is using MySQL 8, which is the only MySQL version supporting this syntax..

Comment: *"I'm not really disputing your point on performance "* i know you removed your comment about table data sizes ... Anyhow we are moving a bit offtopic now..

Comment: Because I'm not trying to get a long debate about this! But alas here we are :)

Comment: *"Because I'm not trying to get a long debate about this! But alas here we are :)"* Yes i also didnt want to start a long debate but we could continue in chat ... :-)

Comment: Well the main problem is not fully scanning those tables which i said wrongly of incomplete in mine first comment as fully table scanning by definition is offcource not always bad, the main point of performance issue is [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) part where MySQL needs to (possibly) convert it into a **disk** based temporary table instead of running it in RAM..  (last comment :-))

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Here are the updates. I want to convert ls.ProdServiceID=(SELECT ProdServiceID FROM ProductServices WHERE ProductID=prod.ProductID ORDER BY Modified DESC LIMIT 1) ; this portion to JOIN. I cannot post results for privacy reasons. I am using mysql version 15.1. By optimization here I mean main the query faster. The Products table has primary indexing on ProductID, and ProductServices has primary indexing on ProductServicesID. Let me know if any other info is needed. @kjmerf thanks! but RANK() & partition are not working with my version of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

try this select query please.
Here you get the serviceid which corresponds to productid and the last modiied

```
SELECT prod.ProductID, prod.Name, prod.ProdExtID, ls.ProdServiceID
FROM Products prod 
LEft join ProductServices ls on ls.ProductID=prod.ProductID
inner JOIN (SELECT  ProductID, max(Modified) as Modified
       FROM
      ProductServices group by ProductID) as ls1 ON ls.ProductID = 
  ls1.ProductID and ls.Modified = ls1.Modified;
```

Comment: Thanks @nbk. Unfortunately, I did not get the expected result. I have added updates in comments, if that can help you to help me out.

Comment: As you can see in this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99888110a45c8466b47f183c79f56c70  example my query works perfectly

Comment: Please change it so that it shows that what you mean.